# Does Quarkus support SOSS Cache (com.scaleoutsoftware.soss)

Tags: quarkus, jcache, scaleout-hserver

My company choose scaleoutsoftware/SOSS as the in-memory cache solution. It is working fine with SpintBoot. Currently, we are migrating all our SprintBoot applications to Quarkus. I cannot get scaleoutsoftware/SOSS work in Quarkus. Seems Quarkus cannot load or process the Jcache configuration in the application.yml. Really appreciate any comments or suggestion.

**This is Quarkus configuration (application.yml):**

```
    quarkus:
      cache:
      type: jcache
      jcache:
         provider: com.scaleoutsoftware.soss.cache.ScaleoutCachingProvider
```

**This is my code:**

```
@Autowired
private javax.cache.CacheManager cacheManager;
```

**This is error I get when I start up Quarkus:**

```
[error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type javax.cache.CacheManager and qualifiers [@Default]
- java member: com.***.cache.DataCacheManager#cacheManager
- declared on CLASS bean [types=[com.***.cache.DataCacheManager, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Named(value = "dataCacheManager"), @Any], target=com.***.cache.DataCacheManager]
```

Comment: Quarkus doesn't support JCache. Where did you find the configuration snippet you use?

Comment: Hi Ladicek, thanks for reply. I just use the same JCache structure of Sprint in the Quarkus configuration.  When I start Quarkus, it doesn't complain about this configuration. So I thought JCache is supported in Quarkus

Comment: Hi Ladicek, could you show me where I can find the information/link about Quarkus doesn't support JCache. I need to show that to our team. Thanks!

Comment: There is no information about Quarkus supporting JCache, therefore, Quarkus doesn't support JCache. If you grep the Quarkus codebase for `jcache`, you don't find anything, which is also a strong hint that the support just isn't there :-) Quarkus supports in-memory caching with Caffeine and out-of-process caching with Redis. It should be possible to write your own implementation for SOSS, or perhaps use SOSS's Redis compatibility with Redis-based caching.

Comment: I just realized I forgot that there's also an extension for remote caching with Infinispan, though that doesn't implement the Quarkus caching API, it exposes the Infinispan API directly (so can't use the Quarkus caching annotations). Using the SOSS API directly should also work well.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ladicek. The information is really helpful!